# field_info_field API to get human readable name

Tags: entities, media

We want get human readable name from field info API.
For e.g. in below API call 
 
**field_info_field('field_image')**

[image]

From UI for Drupal to add Article as below:
[image]

Can we get this human readable names i.e. Title, Alternate Text etc from API.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, no - the labels are set statically in code (in image.field.inc), they don't come from the API:

```
// Add the additional alt and title fields.
$element['alt'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Alternate text'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => isset($item['alt']) ? $item['alt'] : '',
  '#description' => t('This text will be used by screen readers, search engines, or when the image cannot be loaded.'),
  // @see http://www.gawds.org/show.php?contentid=28
  '#maxlength' => 512,
  '#weight' => -2,
  '#access' => (bool) $item['fid'] && $settings['alt_field'],
);
$element['title'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Title'),
  '#default_value' => isset($item['title']) ? $item['title'] : '',
  '#description' => t('The title is used as a tool tip when the user hovers the mouse over the image.'),
  '#maxlength' => 1024,
  '#weight' => -1,
  '#access' => (bool) $item['fid'] && $settings['title_field'],
);
```